# how to abort thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

i use such code

```
List<Thread> list = new List<Thread>();

Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate() { stream(string); });
                this.list.Add(newThread);
                newThread.Start();

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                item.Abort();
            }
        }
```

but after closing the process still runs in task manager, how can i exit whole app?

i googled many times, but all examples are much hard to understand for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your thread as a background thread the thread will be stoped when you exit your main application
like this:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate() { stream(string); });
this.list.Add(newThread);
newThread.isBackground = true;
newThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the debugger.  Attach it if necessary with Tools + Attach to Process.  Debug + Break All, Debug + Windows + Threads shows you what threads are still running.  Use the Thread.IsBackground property to keep your code behind [the left door](http://www.gridshore.nl/wp-content/uploads/code-quality-measurement.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Exit the application:

```
 Application.Exit();
```

Comment: you mean call Application.Exit(); in event FormClosing?

Comment: This only terminates the UI thread, it doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Thread t in threads) t.Join();
```